# socket.io-client redirect to redux thunk middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using **[redux-socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-socket.io)**

I am sending an action from backend server to client from **server.js**

```
soc.emit('action', { type: 'SOCKET_TAG', data: tag });
```

In **store.js** I am creating a store with socket io Middleware

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
...
import createSocketIoMiddleware from 'redux-socket.io';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

let socket = io('ws://127.0.0.1:4000');
let socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, "server/");
let store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger, socketIoMiddleware));
...
```

Actually when I emit the socket action *SOCKET_TAG* from backend the action is executed in the **userReducer**

```
const userReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SOCKET_TAG:
            console.log(actionTypes.SOCKET_TAG, action.data)
            return state;
        default:
            return state
    }
```

But I would like to execute this in the middleware

```
export const initUser = () => {
    const db = client.getServiceClient(RemoteMongoClient.factory, "mongodb-atlas").db(dbName);

    return async (dispatch, getState) => { // async call to database
        let user; // User found with the tag
        client.auth.loginWithCredential(new AnonymousCredential()).then(u =>
            user = db.collection(collectionName).findOne({ tag })
        ).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: actionTypes.INIT_USER, user });
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: actionTypes.ERROR, err });
        });
    }
}
```

I'm new to redux-thunk, **thank you**.

Comment: I found a solution, it's to use [redux-intercept-action](https://github.com/jasonmorita/redux-intercept-action), for me it works but I don't think it's the best way to do it.